# seasonal period m in SARIMA for 15min-data

Tags: python, arima, sarimax

I have data of the strength of the sun's rays every 15 min from March until October. Now I want to make some predictions with SARIMA / SARIMAX. Now I have problems to choose the appropiate saisonal period parameter. Since 15min data should be 35064.

Since the data handles the amount of sun rays I expect a seasonal pattern during the different seasons (summer and winter) as well as patterns during day / night.

So far I've got only error with the period of 35064 therefore I'm not sure if thats the right period to choose.

Error be like e.g.: Unable to allocate 9.16 GiB for an array with shape (35067, 35067, 1) and data type float64
and e.g. the differencing is not possible since I have only about 18000 data entries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to use SARIMA or SARIMAX model when you have such a dataset. You encounter one of the problems i.e. Define the right period on this dataset becomes really challenging.
When datasets start being large, (starting at 10 000 data points or more), deep learning algorithms like CNN, LSTM or autoregressive deep neural network start to be a great tool to obtain accurate forecast and leverage all the available data.